# Why didn't Brad Pitt's character invite his crew in the German women's house?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, fury

In the movie [*Fury* (2014)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2713180/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) at some point our heroes enter a German town and capture it. The main protagonist Donald "Don" "Wardaddy" Collier, played by Brad Pitt (who was a staff sergeant), sees a woman in a window and fetches his newest recruit to go investigate.

Long story short - they find the house the woman is in is empty, save for another girl. So WarDaddy takes the opportunity to have a relaxed meal, prepared by the women, shave, wash, etc.

However, despite being praised by his other subordinates as a leader who looks out for them and wouldn't abandon them, he doesn't invite anyone else to share the meal.

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, despite being praised by his other subordinates as a leader who looks out for them and wouldn't abandon them, he doesn't invite anyone else to share the meal.

Staff Sergeant Donald Collier a.k.a "Wardaddy" does lookout for his troops on battlefield. There is no doubt about that.

But he knows that rest of the crew except Norman and Bible have no respect left for German women. That's why they are not welcomed even when they barge into their "family time".

After having a tough time in the midst of the war he just want to have some quiet time with well behaved Norman and ladies.